# Level, and center, scanned text documents

Tags: pdf, text-processing, scanning

Looking for a program that can level and center the text in scanned pages. Scans are to .pdfs with occasional pictures but mostly text.

My example is the scanning of a paper that was not aligned when going through the ADF or the paper was crooked when placed on the bed. Mostly it is off by only a few degrees but sometimes more. It can get very distracting.

Comment: Which OS/OSes, what price range, are you comfortable with online resources, would you be comfortable installing a programming or scripting language and using it?

Comment: Any OS would be alright. I have and work with Mac, Linux, and Windows. I am comfortable with online resources. Might be able to swing $25 - $50 but no more than that as I am a poor and hungry college student. I do not have a working knowledge of any programming language. Apologies for the late reply.